# Show variable on blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I tried to show  a variable this way on a blade template on laravel

```
<input type="text" name="win-phone" class="modal-input" value="{{ $info['fields']['phone'] }}">
```

and it doesn't work , but this way

```
<input type="text" name="win-phone" class="modal-input" value="{!! $info['fields']['phone'] !!}">
```

It worked, why? the first way its no the correct wat?

Answer (score 5):

By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through `PHP`'s `htmlspecialchars` function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
Hello, {!! $name !!}.
```

In summary, if used in this way disabled HTML is allowed.

Source : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade

Comment: In my case with `{{}}` shows nothing , but the variable doesn't contains html

Comment: If you **share** the variable `$info['fields']['phone']`, we have an idea of what happened.

Comment: Its a numeric string

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to print your `php` variable in `blade` template.

**1.** Statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlspecialchars function to prevent **XSS** attack

```
{{ $your_variable }}
```

**2.** If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax

```
{!! $your_variable !!}
```